# tumblr having large 'empty' overflow to the right when using meta viewport

Tags: overflow, tumblr, viewport

ive put the viewport meta tag into a a tumblr blog and it works fine but there seems to be a large area that scrolls to the right of the body that has nothing in it.

This does not show up on the desktop version so i cant use firebug to see why and im kinda at a loss of how to identify the problem.

I was thinking of setting overflow:hidden; but i didnt think you can do this for only horizontal plus it does not actually address the problem just covers it up.

- the blog in question is www.blog.lightandspace.co.uk
- please see the [THIS SCREEN SHOT](http://pudle.co.uk/sc.png) for example, its from ios sim but its exactly the same on the device (please not the scroll bar at the bottom) ... sorry i can embed it but im a new user and it wont allow me to

any helps much appreciated

cheers

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your viewport width is set to 1224px, which is much wider than the iPhone viewport. Try this instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width maximum-scale=1.4" />
```

This should set the viewport to the width of the device, so it should render nicely on any mobile device.